# store multiple dynamic input fields using laravel jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have the following script which adds dynamically multiple input fields.

My view :

```js
$("body").on("click", ".add_new_frm_field_btn", function() {

  var random = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000); //generate random values..
  var index = $(".form_field_outer").find(".form_field_outer_row").length + 1;
  //added data-index and outer..class
  $(".form_field_outer").append(
    `<div class="col-12 outer" data-index="${index}_${random}">
            <div class="card-body form_field_outer_row"> 
            <div class="form-row"><div class="form-group col-md-4">
             <label for="inputState">Casting</label>
                <select id="id_casting" class="form-control" name="id_casting[]">
                        <option selected>Choose...</option>
                        @foreach($castings as $casting)
                          <option data-id="{{$casting->id_casting}}" value="{{$casting->id_casting}}">{{$casting->nom.' '.$casting->prenom}}</option>
                          @endforeach
                     </select>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group col-md-4"><label for="inputState">Type de contrat</label><select id="id_modele_contrat" class="form-control" name="id_modele_contrat[]"> <option selected>Choose...</option><option>...</option> </select></div><div class="card-body "><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning mb-1 remove_node_btn_frm_field">Delete</button></div>
        </div></div></div> `);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="card mb-4 form_field_outer  ">
  <div class="card-body form_field_outer_row outer" data-index="0">
    <input type="hidden" id="id_projet_casting" name="id_projet_casting" />
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="inputState">Casting</label>
        <select id="id_casting" class="form-control" name="id_casting[]">
          <option selected>Choose...</option>
          @foreach($castings as $casting)
          <option data-id="{{$casting->id_casting}}" value="{{$casting->id_casting}}">{{$casting->nom.' '.$casting->prenom}}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="inputState">Type de contrat</label>
        <select id="id_modele_contrat" class="form-control" name="id_modele_contrat[]">
          <option selected>Choose...</option>
          @foreach($models_contrat as $model_contrat)
          <option data-id="{{$model_contrat->id_modele_contrat}}" value="{{$model_contrat->id_modele_contrat}}">{{$model_contrat->modele_contrat}}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body ">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning mb-1 remove_node_btn_frm_field">Delete</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mb-1 add_new_frm_field_btn">Ajouter un nouveau casting</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I'm trying to store these multiple added inputs into the database, but the problem is only one input field is inserted and not multiple inputs.

I tried with  `dd($request->all());` to see whitch inputs are token when I add multiple inputs I get :

```
 "id_casting" => array:1 [
    0 => "Choose..."
  ]
  "id_modele_contrat" => array:1 [
    0 => "Choose..."
  ]
```

As you see there is only one element in the array while there is multiple inputs field

What is wrong with my code?

If you have any idea help me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take multiple values from a select element then you have to mark it as multiple. Or you may use Checkbox.

```html
<select multiple name="id_casting[]">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Thank you for ur answer, but this is not what I want , I should get value o multiple rows of selected-box